Showing $\sum_{cyc}\frac{\cos^2A}{1+\cos A} \geq \frac12$ for acute $\triangle ABC$

If $A+B+C = \pi$ and $0< A,B,C < \frac{\pi}2$, then:
$$\frac{\cos^2(A)}{1+\cos(A)} +\frac{\cos^2(B)}{1+\cos(B)} +\frac{\cos^2(C)}{1+\cos(C)} \geq \frac12$$

I used Lagrange's multipliers and Calculus to figure out that indeed $\frac12$ is one of the minimum values, I just didn't prove that aren't others. I believe there is a smarter way to solve this. It is not impossible to use Jensen's inequality here and obtain that:
$$\frac{\cos^2(A)}{1+\cos(A)}+\frac{\cos^2(B)}{1+\cos(B)}+\frac{\cos^2(C)}{1+\cos(C)} \ge \frac{(\cos A +\cos B +\cos C )^2}{3+\cos A +\cos B +\cos C }$$
But I believe this is not strong enough, the inf of the right side above is $\frac1{4}$.
Any ideas?

What do you mean by "one of the minimum values"? Can there be two?

yes, in calculus you can have non global minimums

for sure, but if you use Lagrange's multipliers, which two different local minima did you obtain?

the other ones are more complex than the one  got making $A=B=C$, they're hard to obtain algebraically, probably need to solve a cubic.

Some questions can't get nice answers. Or İ think so.

@BobDobbs yeah, apparently. But the link to the other question does solve this one.

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet so I'll leave a link to a similar question here.
Prove that $ \frac{x^2}{1+x} + \frac{y^2}{1+y} + \frac{z^2}{1+z} \geq \frac{1}{2} $
